# Spam protection onclick()

Tags: java, android, onclick

I'm trying to build a SMS application that sends a SMS with one press on a button, this part is working but now I'm trying to implement a spam protection. 
The spam protection means that you only can send 1 SMS per 10 seconds (or higher).

I've tried this:

```java
sentSMS.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {

       Timer timer = new Timer();

       int seconds = 10000;
       timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
           public void run() {
               processClick();
           }
       }, seconds);

}});
```

But this is not working when I press the button twice the SMS is also sending twice.

Maybe it's also a idea to make a toast which contains how many seconds the user have to wait, something like this:

```java
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Spam protection, wait "+secondstowait,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Is this all possible to make?

Comment: In your current code, the logic schedules an SMS to happen in 1 second from each click, regardless of when the last time the button was pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store when the button was last clicked and then see if 10 seconds have passed.

```
long lastTimeSent = 0; //start at 0


sentSMS.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {

   if(System.currentTimeMillis() > lastTimeSent + 10000){ //if at least 10 secs has passed from last click
       processClick();
       lastTimeSent = System.currentTimeMillis(); //last time sent is now current time
   }else{
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Spam protection, please wait.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}});
```

Comment: Thanks I'll use this with combination of this toast: `long value = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimeSent;  double result = 10.0 - value / 1000.0;  String wait = String.format("%.0f", result);  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Spam protection, please wait "+wait+" sec.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: That should do it :-)

Answer (score 5):

why dont you just take a timestamp when the button was first clicked then compare the time when the button was clicked again and see if the difference is greater than the allotted amount of time?

Answer (score 2):

Potentially, the easier thing to do in my opinion is to disable the button, and use the built-in handler (on the view object) to re-enable the button.

```
sentSMS.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
       final View view = v;
       v.setEnabled(false);
       v.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                 view.setEnabled(true);
            }
       }, 1000*10);    
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show a toast message to user, notifying him about how many seconds are left,
you must write the toast.maketext code inside the timer schedule event too

using timestamp will not be easier way, rather it will make task more difficult.

You can also try to disable the button onclick for ten seconds and re-enable it after the time period is expired.